# Visualization of polygon data using OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers, visualization

I have 3.7 million small polygons and I want to create a heat map from it. Since it has a lot of points, reading from a JavaScript array and drawing on map is not possible. Is there any efficient way to do it?

Thanks.

Comment: Where is the polygon data stored? You can probably use geoserver to create the layer.

Comment: Data is stored in geodatabase. How can I create the layer?

Comment: Did you have a look at heatmaps with CartoDB? http://blog.cartodb.com/introducing-heatmaps/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMHO, 3.7 million polygons look a bit heavy for the Javascript. A good way is generating the heatmap on the server. If you are using Geoserver you can follow the [rendering transfomations example](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/styling/sld/extensions/rendering-transform.html) from the official documentation. Remember that using Rendering Transformations requires the [WPS extension](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/services/wps/install.html) to be installed (but not need to be enabled).

After configuring the heatmap representation, the OpenLayers client just consume that layer.